# Is there any way to merge lazy chunk files with Initial chunk files in angular 13?

Tags: angular, infragistics, webpack-production

I am trying to merge my angular app production build into one single js file.
Everything works fine but one of the dependencies I have used is creating a lazy chunk file. I have used the Infragistics doc manager library https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular/angular/components/dock-manager and the chunk related to that package is created as a separate file.

I want to merge it with the main.js file. Is there any way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: looking for the same answer

Comment: any solution on this?